# Use Custom fields AFC image field as background in the product archive loop

Tags: php, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

Instead of outputting the Custom fields AFC image field as an regular image, i want it do render as an div with the image as background.

```
$myImg = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'product_img', true );
    $imgSrc = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $myImg );


    if ( ! empty( $myImg ) ) {
        echo '<div style="background-image: url(<?php echo $imgSrc [0]; ?> );"></div>';
    }
```

This string does work with my other Custom fields, but doesn't seems to render anything with the image field.

Answer (score 1):

If you're inside the product archive loop you can just retrieve and display as such:

**If your image field is set to Image URL:**

```
<?php $myImg = get_field('product_img');
if($myImg):?>
    <div style="background-image: url('<?php echo $myImg;>');"></div>
<?php endif;?>
```

**If your image field is set to Image Object:**

```
<?php $myImg = get_field('product_img');
if($myImg):?>
    <div style="background-image: url('<?php echo $myImg['url'];>');"></div>
<?php endif;?>
```

There is no need to check if the variable is not empty as using get_field() does that checking for you.

Answer (score 0):

ACF field usage

```php
echo '<div style="background-image: url(' . get_field("image_field") . ');">';
```

WP default method:

```php
$myImg = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'product_img', true );
   $imgSrc = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $myImg );


    if ( ! empty( $myImg ) ) {
        echo '<div style="background-image: url('. $imgSrc [0] . ' );"></div>';
    }
```